# How do I get the iAD methods to get called

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, iad

I am trying to display iADs into my cocos2d game scene. I am able to successfully display ads, but I want to be able to show the view controller on screen only when the ad is being displayed.

So for this I tried to use the -(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner method which I believed would get called if I added it in my view controllers implementation. But it doesn't get called at all. Below is my code.

Can you kindly let me know if I am doing anything wrong. Thanks :)

BannerAd.h

```
@interface BannerAd:  UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
    id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ADBannerView *adView;

-(id)init: (id) dele;
-(void) removeAd;
-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner;

@end
```

BannerAd.m

```
@implementation BannerAd

@synthesize adView = adView_;

-(id)init: (id) dele
{
    if((self=[super init]))
    {
        NSLog(@"init called, delegate set");
        delegate = dele;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    [self.view addSubview:self.adView];
}

-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"AD did load");
}
```

Inside my game scene(cocos2d scene) i call this:

```
    BannerAd *bannerAdDetailView = [[BannerAd alloc] init];
    [bannerAdDetailView init:self];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view] addSubview:bannerAdDetailView.view];
    [bannerAdDetailView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
```

Kindly let me know how i can make sure my app is notified when the ad gets loaded.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `ADBannerView` delegate (add to `viewDidLoad` method):

```
self.adView.delegate = self;
```

This tells the banner view who is the target of the method call `bannerViewDidLoadAd`. In this case its your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Ad Banner View Delegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009581): – bannerViewDidLoadAd: in this method you could set the banner view visible.
Here is the reference if no ad was loaded: [Hide Bannerview when no ad was received](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html).

Comment: As I have mentioned, I know which one to use. I just have trouble implementing it. The bannerViewDidLoadAd method is not getting called..Am I adding it in the right place? Thanks